# drush does not work properly on vagrant

Tags: drupal-7, vagrant, drush

I am trying to create an omega subtheme and believe it's better to work with drush than manually.

I have a test project on a vagrant box. In my Ubuntu I have installed drush, but I am probably doing something wrong.

For example, `drush dl` works, but `drush en` and `drush omega` does not.

Comment: Could you describe what errors you're seeing? Saying something doesn't work isn't really enough for us to go on - how does it not work, what does it tell you?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I have reread what your question was asking and I want to ask, is the theme not being enabled at all or is it not setting it as the default theme? If you want it to be your default theme you will have to use a different command than **drush en**. You should instead **drush vset admin_theme theme_name**.  Here is a link below:

http://www.paulbooker.co.uk/drupal-developer/command-lines/changing-sites-default-theme-and-admin-theme-using-drush

I will leave my vagrant information in case that is helpful to others too.

---

---

---

---

Could you provide us with the error you are receiving when you try to use drush?  In the vagrant folder (where you specify vagrant up) you need to call

```
vagrant ssh
```

to ssh into your vagrant and then go into your proper site directory where drupal is installed.  Without a drupal instance drush will not exist.

If you are using VDD for your drupal vagrant development, I would recommend following this tutorial on drupal.org:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2008792

Let me know if you have any other details on your issues or any more questions.